# reasking for declined permissions in fb js sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I'm using `FB.getLoginStatus()` to check for login which will display authorization dialog in case it's needed.
the case here, if that the user unchecked email from the below screen, the screen will not attempt to re-ask the user by displaying the dialog, and calling FB.login will result in a warning that user is already authenticated. there is a way i can pass a scope with recheck option to `FB.getLoginStatus()`? or any other solutions to set me on the right track

```
function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        //console.log('statusChangeCallback');
        //console.log(response);
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // Logged into your app and Facebook.
            LogUserIn();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            //console.log('you must authorize the app');
            alert(message);
        } else {
            //console.log('Please log into Facebook.');
        }
    });
}
```

[image: auth dialog]

Answer (score 6):

From facebook documentation:

It's OK to ask a person once to grant your app permissions that they've declined. You should have a screen of education on why you think they should grant the permission to you and then re-ask. But if you use the method described in the [previous section)(#re-launching-permissions-dialog) the Login Dialog won't ask for that permission.

This is because once someone has declined a permission, the Login Dialog will not re-ask them for it unless you explicitly tell the dialog you're re-asking for a declined permission.

You do this by adding the auth_type: rerequest flag to your FB.login() call:

```
FB.login(
  function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  {
    scope: 'user_likes',
    auth_type: 'rerequest'
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0 and specifically the Re-asking for Declined Permissions section